# VB.NET: Get strings from lines between words

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to find a way to grab the strings that are included between two words but I cannot figure out how to do it. I need each line to be added to a listbox.

For example:

```
First:
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
default

Second:
http://facebook.com
http://123.com
http://test.com
default
```

Using this as an example, the first listbox needs to include the following items:

```
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
default
```

And the second listbox should include those items:

```
http://facebook.com
http://123.com
http://test.com
default
```

How is this possible? I only know how to get a string between two words using split but it doesn't work in this case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean there may be any number of lines between first ad default. But the block contains the above mentioned strings.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The example is random.

Comment: did you wan to capture http://google.com or yahoo.com

Comment: @user2921419 Do you mean something like this [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gB1eI7/1)?

Comment: What are your delimiters?

Comment: Yes Dalorzo that's what I want to get. Each line separately as a listbox item.

Comment: Where is this input coming from, a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your data, you may consider using a Negative Lookahead to match the lines you want only.

```
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, "(?m)^(?!(?:First|Second):).+$")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(m.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?<=\n|^)First:(?:(?!\n\n).)*?(http://google\.com)(?:(?!\n\n|$).)*?(http://yahoo\.com)(?:(?!\n\n).)*?default(?=\n\n)|(?<=\n|^)Second:(?:(?!\n\n).)*?(http://facebook\.com)(?:(?!\n\n).)*?(http://123\.com)(?:(?!\n\n).)*?(http://test\.com)(?:(?!\n\n).)*?default(?=\n\n|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hI3bO1/1)

Comment: I would come up with a better way to do this then listing static urls that are posted as an `example` in the OPs question...

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
(?<=First:)(.*)
```

[**Online RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gB1eI7/2)

With this code:

```
Dim options = RegexOptions.Singleline
Dim sampleInput="First:" + Environment.NewLine  + "http://google.com" + Environment.NewLine  + "http://yahoo.com" + Environment.NewLine  + "default"
Dim results = Regex.Match(sampleInput,"(?<=First:)(.*)",options).Value
```

[**Code Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hUdicF)